# Get a Row if within certain time period of other row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL statement that I am currently using to return a number of rows from a database:

```
SELECT
    as1.AssetTagID, as1.TagID, as1.CategoryID,
    as1.Description, as1.HomeLocationID, as1.ParentAssetTagID
FROM Assets AS as1
    INNER JOIN AssetsReads AS ar  ON as1.AssetTagID = ar.AssetTagID
WHERE
    (ar.ReadPointLocationID='Readpoint1' OR ar.ReadPointLocationID='Readpoint2')
    AND (ar.DateScanned between 'LastScan' AND 'Now')
    AND as1.TagID!='000000000000000000000000'
```

I am wanting to do a query that will get the row with the oldest `DateScanned` from this query and also get another row from the database if there was one that was within a certain period of time from this row (say 5 seconds for an example). The oldest record would be relatively simple by selecting the first record in a descending sort, but how would I also get the second record if it was within a certain time period of the first?

I know I could do this process with multiple queries, but is there any way to combine this process into one query?

The database that I am using is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Also please note that the `DateScanned` times are just placeholders and I am taking care of that in the application that will be using this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fairly general way to approach it.  Get the oldest scan date using `min()` as a window function, then use date arithmetic to get any rows you want:

```
select t.*  -- or whatever fields you want
from (SELECT as1.AssetTagID, as1.TagID, as1.CategoryID,
             as1.Description, as1.HomeLocationID, as1.ParentAssetTagID,
             min(DateScanned) over () as minDateScanned, DateScanned
      FROM Assets AS as1
           INNER JOIN AssetsReads AS ar  ON as1.AssetTagID = ar.AssetTagID
      WHERE (ar.ReadPointLocationID='Readpoint1' OR ar.ReadPointLocationID='Readpoint2')
            AND (ar.DateScanned between 'LastScan' AND 'Now')
            AND as1.TagID!='000000000000000000000000'
     ) t
where datediff(second, minDateScanned, DateScanned) <= 5;
```

Comment: I was thinking I should be doing something with `datediff`, but just couldn't figure out what. Thanks, this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure of `sql server` syntax, but you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    TOP 2
    as1.AssetTagID, 
    as1.TagID, 
    as1.CategoryID, 
    as1.Description, 
    as1.HomeLocationID, 
    as1.ParentAssetTagID ,
    ar.DateScanned,
    LAG(ar.DateScanned) OVER (order by ar.DateScanned desc) AS lagging
  FROM 
    Assets AS as1
    INNER JOIN AssetsReads AS ar
      ON as1.AssetTagID = ar.AssetTagID
  WHERE (ar.ReadPointLocationID='Readpoint1' OR ar.ReadPointLocationID='Readpoint2')
    AND (ar.DateScanned between 'LastScan' AND 'Now')
    AND as1.TagID!='000000000000000000000000'
  ORDER BY
    ar.DateScanned DESC  
)
WHERE 
  lagging IS NULL or DateScanned - lagging < '5 SECONDS'
```

I have tried to sort the results by `DateScanned desc` and then just the top most 2 rows. I have then used the `lag()` function on DateScanned field, to get the `DateScanned` value for the previous row. For the topmost row the `DateScanned` shall be null as its the first record, but for the second one it shall be value of the first row. You can then compare both of these values to determine whether you wish to display the second row or not

**more info** on the lagging function: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like it would work, but unfortunately I'm getting a nice `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name.` in my C# code. I'm looking for a solution for that right now, and apparently this is valid for SQL Server. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently, `LAG` only works for SQL Server 2012. Any ideas for 2008 R2?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it, Gordon Linoff has given a good answer ;)